# Fixing a proof on triangles in graphs

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and at least $\lfloor {n^2/4}\rfloor+1$ edges, Then $G$ contains at least $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ triangles.

This can be proven using induction by removing a single vertex. However, the following alternative proof (taken from the first paragraph [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~dc340/EGTSheet1Sol.pdf) ) claims to prove the same more elegantly by removing *two* vertices. The end of this proof seems somewhat unjustified for me, and I'd like to know why it is true.

I understand the following: Assume there are less than $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ triangles. We note that there is an edge $xy$ in $G$ that is not part of a triangle, and that the graph $H$ obtained by removing $x$ and $y$ from $G$ has, by induction, at least $\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1$ triangles. Now we only need to find one more triangle, and it enough to see that $N^*(x)$ (the punctured neighborhood of x) or $N^*(y)$ contain an edge. Asume to the contrary that both $N^*(x)$ and $N^*(y)$ are independent sets. Then we there are at most $\lfloor \frac{{n-2}^2}{4}\rfloor$ edges joining $N^*(x)$ to $N^*(y)$.

However, I don't see how to proceed; where is the contradiction that implies that there must indeed be an edge in $N^*(x)$ or in $N^*(y)$? Moreover, looking at a clique $K_{n-2}$ together with an additional edge $xy$ seems to be a counterexample to the proof. So is the argument really flawed? If so, can it be fixed?

**Sidenote**. If I knew that $H$ consists solely of vertices from $N^*(x)$ and from $N^*(y)$ then I would have known how to finish: $H$ has at least $\lfloor \frac{{n-2}^2}{4}\rfloor+1$ edges and only $\lfloor \frac{{n-2}^2}{4}\rfloor$ edges joining $N^*(x)$ to $N^*(y)$ so $N^*(y)$ or $N^*(x)$ must contain an edge.

Comment: This seems not to be true for $n=2$

Comment: Still not true for $n=2$

Comment: Can you please elaborate? If we have two vertices and two edges we definitely have a triangle in the sense of multigraphs. (And if we only care about simple graphs then it is vacuously true).

Comment: I don't think you have 1 triangle in a graph of size 2.

Comment: The proof is correct. $K_{n-2}$ would not fit with the assumption of less than $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ triangles. Which edge are you concerned about? $xy$, or the one in the neighbourhood?

Comment: I'm concerned about the existence of an edge in one of the neighborhoods. In other words, I don't understand how we finish the proof after the paragraph of things that I understood: Where is the contradiction? Why did we note the number of edges joining the two neighborhoods?

Comment: We are removing at most $n-2$ edges from $x$ and $y$ (no overlap because that would be a triangle), and the edge $xy$ itself, so less than $n-1$ edges. That leaves us with at least $\lfloor \frac{(n-2)^2}{4}\rfloor+1$ edges after $x$ and $y$ are removed. Only $\lfloor \frac{(n-2)^2}{4}\rfloor$ of these can be accounted for between $N(x)$ and $N(y)$, so at least one edge is inside one of them (say $N(x)$). That edge plus the two edges leading from either end of it to $x$ forms an extra triangle.

Comment: Yes, but there may be edges counted among those $\lfloor \frac{{n-2}^2}{4}\rfloor+1$ edges that are neither connecting the neighborhoods neither inside the neighborhoods.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be solved, by proving a more general solution.

Let $G$ be a graph with $n\geq 3$ vertices and at least $\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\rfloor+k$ edges, for $1\leq k\leq \lfloor\frac{n-2}{6}\rfloor$. Then $G$ contains at least k$\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ triangles. The upper limit on $k$ is a bit of a fiddle, and means you may need to establish things a bit more.

But the proof is then saved, I think.

You can still find edge $(x,y)$ that's not in any triangles, since $3(k\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor-1)\leq \lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\rfloor+1$.

Then adding in the edges from $x$ and $y$, at most one of those edges can be in $H$, since you add at least $\lfloor\frac{n-2}{2}\rfloor\geq k$ triangles per edge added to $H$.

I haven't done this rigorously, but I think you might be able to save the proof.

It's always tricky to find faults in proofs of true results, so good job on spotting this gap!!